# Imdb api with flash - as3 - flex

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, imdb

I am trying to use the imdb API, in this case: http://imdbapi.org/ 
I need to search for a movie by name and get a json, then load an image with the poster obtained.
I'll be using as3 - flex to generate an Air package.

I tried this example, but can't seem to get it right.

```
import flash.net.*;
var url:String = "http://imdbapi.org/";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.name = "Pulp fiction";
request.data = variables;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
loader.load(request);

function onComplete (event:Event):void {
    trace(event.target.data);
}
```

Perhaps you could enlight me with an example of connecting to the api and retrieving that json so that I can load an image with the poster and generate my air package.

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you please tell us what "can't seem to get it right means".  Is there a compiler error with your code?  Or a runtime error?  Or do you get unexpected results back?

Comment: I created an as3 flex project and I addead a class where I put the code I pasted here when I run it I get a white window. No errors.

Comment: IF there are no errors; then what is the problem you need help solving?  The code you shared has no code to display anything, so a "White screen" is expected.

Comment: I have this <code> textField = new TextField();
   textField.text = "Hello World.";
  
   addChild(textField);</code> I only have this connection class, should I mark anything else to run it as a main? I'm using an as3flex project

Comment: You don't seem to be using Flex Framework classes; are you sure you meant to tag this question with Flex?  Given the short snippet of code, I would have expected you would see "Hello World" text.  Is your problem the fact that hello world text doesn't show up in your app? or that you are having issues calling the IMDB API?

Comment: Unless you just aren't showing it, all variables/objects/functions in classes need to have access modifiers (private, public, protected, etc) and you can't just have code floating around outside of a function like that. Create a constructor or (if using Flex, which it seems you're not, if you're using TextField) add an "initialize" or "creationComplete" handler which has this code in it.

Comment: the code is inside this:    ?xml version="1.0"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
 <mx:Script>
  <![CDATA[ ...      then I set a label.text = what i get from json. Thats what im trying at least

Comment: I got it to bring the Json, I'm trying to parse it now so I can get the info and the image with the poster.

Comment: @Apocalyptic0n3 If no access modifier is specified; then it gets set to internal.  I think it throws a warning from the Flex Compiler, but is not an error.  It is highly unusual to leave that out; I'm surprised I didn't notice that missing.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com I figured it defaulted to something, wasn't sure though. Wasn't even aware you could compile like that (though I did just test it by removing a modifier from stable code and it all works just fine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API seems to want the movie in the `q` param so change this

```
variables.name = "Pulp fiction";
```

to :

```
variables.q = "Pulp fiction";
```

To verify : http://imdbapi.org/?q=Pulp%20Fiction

From there getting the poster URL is just a matter of reading the correct property from the JSON string.

```
private function onComplete (event:Event):void {
    var data:Array = JSON.parse(event.target.data);
    if(data && data.length)
    {
       var movie:Object = data[0];
       trace(movie.poster);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get access of undefined property JSON when I compile

Comment: The global JSON object is available if you are targeting flash player 11 and up. If not you need to download the adobe lib that has the json parsing class.